# cannot connect to local MySql server through console

Tags: php, mysql

My server getting that "cannot connect to local MySql server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)". error when connect mysql through the command line.

What I changed is move the mysql data directory / socket to the new folder.

Everything working fine. I changed the start up script, my.cnf to reflect the new location for the data and the socket.

The only problem is if I just run mysql on command line, I got that error.  if I put -h 127.0.0.1 then all good.

Any idea how to fix it? I'm sure in the my.cnf, all the client & mysqld section were updated to the new location. same as phpMyAdmin, I need to change to 127.0.0.1 instead of using "localhost", otherwise, I can't connect at all.

Answer (score 0):

IS this path
    /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
the correct path to your moved socket path?

If not, then you miss to change a parameter.

You can also try to connect with the socket-parameter

```
mysql -uroot -p --socket=/pathtoyour/new.sock
```

BR Chris

Comment: It works for that statement, but once I exit and try again "mysql" , the error comes up again. It is not stay for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add socket path under section [mysql] of your my.cnf file. This is used by mysql client programs. Restart MySQL service after this change.
e.g.
`[mysql]`

```
socket = <yourpathtosockfile>
```

Answer (score 0):

Connect to your mysql server on the command line using `-h 127.0.0.1` and run this query:

```
show global variables where Variable_name = 'socket';
```

This will give you the value of socket file that is being used by the mysql server. Next, edit your `my.cnf` file and search for `[client]`, if not found you can add it.

```
[client]
socket = <the path you got from above query>
```

If it still doesn't work after adding those configuration parameters in the global `my.cnf` file then it means there is another `my.cnf` file that is overriding your global one with wrong configuration. Depending on your operating system the path to the `my.cnf` files that mysql client reads before starting varies. The list is available at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html

Comment: Thanks but the path it show in the query is exactly matched what I put in the my.cnf file under by [client] and [mysqld] section.Must be somewhere else, but I have no idea, now I only can use127.0.0.1 and can't use the "locahost" anymore.

Comment: I search the server which is redhat 6.5, I only find one my.cnf

Comment: Yes, only one my.cnf sitting in /usr/ folder, I moved that to /etc/ and the error go away, but when restart the mysql, it stop OK, but just stuck in start, then I check the status it is show running, all fine, just not return the OK when start it? any idea.